# Array.push not pushing properly

Tags: javascript, jquery, express, npm, cheerio

EDIT: I've added the res.send(json), wasn't included the snippet.

I'm trying to extract/scrape a website and combine their output into json data.  However when I run the endpoint, the response combines every result into its key, instead of adding a record per iteration.  To expound, I get:

```
{ 
      item: "item1item2item3item4item5item6",
      title: "title1title2title3title4title5title5",
      price: "price1price2price3price4price5price6"
}
```

This is my target output format though..:

```
{ item: "item1",
  title: "title1",
  price: "price1",
  itemlink: "itemlink1" },
{ item: "item2",
  title: "title2",
  price: "price2",
  itemlink: "itemlink2" },
{ item: "item3",
  title: "title3",
  price: "price3",
  itemlink: "itemlink3" }, etc...
```

Here's the below snippet:

```
    request(url, function(error, response, html){
    if(!error){
        var $ = cheerio.load(html);

    var json = [];
    /* Pulls out all the titles
    $('.item-name').each(function() {
        var title = $(this).text();
        json2.push({title: title});
    })
    */

    function getID(str) {
        return str.split('viewitem.php?iid=')[1];
    }

    $('.catlist').each(function(key, index) {
        var title = $('.item-name').text();
        var price = $('.catprice').text();
        var id = getID($('h2').children().attr('href'));
        var itemlink = $('h2').children().attr('href');

        json.push({     
            id: id, 
            title: title, 
            price: price, 
            itemlink: itemlink 
        });
    })

}
res.send(json)

})
```

I'm out of my wits, already spent hours on this.  Any idea why they are not iterating properly for me? Thanks in advance!

Comment: Diff you try investigating this (... Use a debugger)?

Comment: You are changing json's value but not pushing ad new value into the array

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
 $('.catlist').each(function(key, index) {
    var title = $(this).find('.item-name').text();
    var price = $(this).find('.catprice').text();
    var id = getID($(this).find('h2').children().attr('href'));
    var itemlink = $(this).find('h2').children().attr('href');

    var temp = 
    {   
        id: id, 
        title: title, 
        price: price, 
        itemlink: itemlink 
    };
    json.push(temp);
})
```

You need to find children for each `.catlist` and push them to array one by one

Comment: thanks, the "(this)" actually helped.  At first when I tried your fix, I realized my CSS selector was just selected one child.  I changed it to "$('.catlist').find('li').each(function(key, index) {"  and it worked.  Guess it's hard to help without seeing the site being scraped. ;) Thanks for your help.

Comment: When you write and learn more you will build up your own bug detector. :)

Answer (score 0):

As you can see in your code you are assigning value to json in every iteration. So that's why it's not adding new record to it. 
Have a look to this code

```
 $('.catlist').each(function(key, index) {
        var title = $('.item-name').text();
        var price = $('.catprice').text();
        var id = getID($('h2').children().attr('href'));
        var itemlink = $('h2').children().attr('href');

        var temp = 
        {   
            id: id, 
            title: title, 
            price: price, 
            itemlink: itemlink 
        };
        json.push(temp);
    })
```

Answer (score -1):

Try this

```
 json.push( {
   id: id, 
   title: title, 
   price: price,
   itemlink: itemlink 
 });
```